# Usernames are evil. How can I make Restful Authentication only require an email address and password, instead of a username too?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, restful-authentication

As the title says: how can I use the Restful Authentication Plugin with Ruby on Rails. When I want to create a new user, it requires me to set the (wrong-named, confusing field) `login` (= username), `email address` and `password`. However, I want, like Facebook does, to require the user to enter only an email address and password, not a username. People will also login with this email address.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Oh thanks Brandon and Michael ^^, I looked in the rivision history and noticed I made an epic fail...

Answer (score 1):

Can you hash the email to a unique user-name and just never expose the field to the user?

Comment: But that's so messy, isn't there really no cleaner way?

Answer (score 1):

Restful Authentication includes generators that set up your models and migrations.  You're free to edit those as you see fit.

You would just need to edit the validations in the User model for the login field.  I'm not sure if the default users table migration include `:null=>false` for the login field, but that's a simple fix as well.

Answer (score 0):

Set the username and email to the same value?

Answer (score 0):

What BlueRaja says, or use [authlogic](http://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic), which can easily be modified to support what you are trying to achieve.

Also, if you're going to do this, why not go the next step and support OpenId?  It's available as an [addon to authlogic](http://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic_openid).

Answer (score 0):

I forked a version of restful auth and modified it to not use usernames. Not thouroughly tested with all options but it passes the tests. Check it out if you want: https://github.com/jamiequint/restful-authentication